# How to solve this error IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logging.yaml' ?

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to use a python library "google_news_crawler" that can be installed through "pip install google_news_crawler" when I run its example code.

```
google_news_crawler --datastore=ES --feed="http://news.google.com/news?cf=all&ned=en_bw&output=rss&topic=t&sort=newest"
```

its gives me an error like this:

```
-HP-Notebook:~$ google_news_crawler --datastore=ES --feed="http://news.google.com/news?cf=all&ned=en_bw&output=rss&topic=t&sort=newest"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/google_news_crawler", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_news_crawler/google_news_crawler.py", line 46, in main
    setup_logging(args['--log-config'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_news_crawler/google_news_crawler.py", line 36, in setup_logging
    with open(fname) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logging.yaml'
```

I really don't have any clue what is 'logging.yaml' file and how can I solve this error.

thanks

Comment: try copying that file from project's repo, https://bitbucket.org/ilps/google_news_crawler/src/

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_news_crawler/
sudo touch logging.yaml
sudo vi logging.yaml
```

Copy paste below content into that file:

```
disable_existing_loggers: false
formatters:
  default:
    format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s'
    #datefmt: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: default
loggers:
  google_news_crawler.gnc:
    level: DEBUG
  elasticsearch:
    level: ERROR
  elasticsearch.trace:
    handlers: null
root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: WARNING
version: 1
```